# java/nio/charset/Charsets error in Android Studio using DatePicker

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, datepicker, android-studio

I receive this error in Android Studio when I try to render a DatePicker:

```
 Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: java/nio/charset/Charsets
```

When I delete the DataPicker from raw XML the error dissappears and I can work normally with my layout, but as soon as I try to add a DataPicker this error appears and I cannot see any component in the Component Tree, nor any activity in the activity view (where I operate with the design of my layout).

I'm using API 16 to render the layout (since APIs 17 & 18 are broken with CalendarView & DataPicker) and for locale I have es-ES.

What can I do to solve this error or, at least, be able to work in Design view with a DataPicker?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of android studio? There's a change in 2.9 (http://tools.android.com/recent) that describes your error.

Comment: The same problem appears in issue #7 here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59732#c7 , but using a CalendarView instead a DatePicker. And yes, I'm using latest Android Studio version (0.3.1) - Build Number AI-132.883541